Insert different formated date in django
I have a Date input field in my form like below.
<label class="form-label">Date of Birth</label>
{{ form.date_of_birth }}  
{% if form.date_of_birth.errors %}
   <div class="alert alert-danger">{{ form.date_of_birth.errors }}</div>
{% endif %}

I am trying to insert date 08/06/2024. I am getting error Enter a valid date.. I am using below code in forms.py.
date_of_birth = forms.DateField(
   required=True,
   input_formats=['%d/%m/%Y']  
)

I am using below code in settings.py.
DATE_INPUT_FORMATS = ['%d/%m/%Y']


In your form.py, ensure you use this code mate, settings.DATE_INPUT_FORMATS by importing it directly from settings.py through the usage of django.conf.settings module, not as you did it in the form.
What is your USE_LION setting in settings.py, if it is set to True, try setting it to False that can help depending on your localization.

Thanks @Blaisemart. Could you please explain your solution ?

When I read your code line by line to possibly identify the error, I discovered two things might be what is causing the error which I answered above. Firstly, you are overriding the DATE_INPUT FORMATS in your forms.py which you had stated to Django in the settings.py to use, which you didn't, Django doesn't allow that, and your code is likely going to misbehave (throw an error) if you do that. Secondly,  USE_L10N - is a Django concept or terminology that involves adapting your Datetime to your localization, when set to TRUE, Django will adapt to your localization immediately.

For more info, check our Django docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/i18n/

If my answer prefers a solution to your issue, kindly tick it good, so that if another developer with a similar issue stumbles to your title with a similar issue, they can find it very useful to solve their challenge. @abuabu

Thanks @Blaisemart. Actually I would like to save value 08/06/2024 in database through Form submit. How can I do that ?

That is very simple to do, you can achieve that through your views.py or models.py by calling save() method.  Whichever one you want to use is perfect. However, we would like to see your views.py. Remember, this is entirely another question and it is different  from the question you answered previously based on StackOverflow rules, you need to ask it separately, and you can possibly tag me to solve it ASAP or tag any Django Dev to do that for you.
